# What is the function type of the last parameter of the ForEach struct from SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Context: I'm following the tutorial on https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/ to get an introduction to Swift and iOS.

In learning about closure notation in Swift, I wanted to write the more expanded version of a closure I came across.

```
ForEach(filteredLandmarks) {
  landmark in
      NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
    }
}
```

The first code snippet works great.

From what I understand about trailing closures, is that the type of the function needed as the last argument to the `ForEach` struct is implies the type of the function defined by the closure, hence we don't need to explicitly say the type of the function defined by the closure and refer only to it's one and only argument `landmark` implicitly. But what is the type if I wanted to explicitly define it?

The following is my attempt, which produces the error in Xcode

> value of protocol type 'View' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

```
ForEach(filteredLandmarks) {
  (landmark: Landmark) -> View in
      NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
    }
}
```

I know `landmark` has a type of `Landmark`, because removing the `-> View` works perfectly. So really, all I need to know is what is the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6oy5i):

```
init(_ data: Data, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

<sub>(Available when `Data` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`, `ID` is `Data.Element.ID`, `Content` conforms to `View`, and `Data.Element` conforms to `Identifiable`.)</sub>

As you can see, the closure is supposed to return `Content`. What is `Content`?

`ForEach` is actually a generic type, and `Data` and `Content` are actually the generic type parameters of `ForEach`:

```
struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> 
    where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable
```

This means that *you* get to decide what `Content` is.

Using `-> View` doesn't work, because for that initialiser to be available, `Content` must conform to `View`. [`View` does not conform to `View`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/5133585), so you can't do that.

In your code, you are returning a `NavigationLink`, and that is indeed the type of `Content` for `ForEach`. You should do:

```
(landmark: Landmark) -> NavigationLink in
```

***However***, the catch is, [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) is also generic! You must specify its generic parameters!

The type of the `destination` parameter is the second generic parameter, and the view you return in the trailing closure is its first generic parameter. Assuming `LandmarkDetail` and `LandmarkRow` are not generic, you'd need to do:

```
(landmark: Landmark) -> NavigationLink<LandmarkRow, LandmarkDetail> in
```

Note that most of the time when writing SwiftUI, such analysis of what type the closure returns is not possible. Suppose you did:

```
ForEach(filteredLandmarks) {
  landmark in
      NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark).padding()
    }
}
```

instead, then we would not be able to know the exact type of the first generic parameter of `NavigationLink`, as `padding` returns an [opaque type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html) of `some View`. Note that you can do this in your closure return type too:

```
(landmark: Landmark) -> some View in
```

Comment: Awesome! I was having a hard time finding the init documentation for anything I was searching for as it appears after examples which I wasn't expecting. I wouldn't say "such analysis of what type the closure returns is not possible". The example of an opaque type being returned is very helpful and informative, but that is exactly what type is being returned, so such analysis is definitely possible, just with an opaque type, instead of a regular type, as you stated. Maybe say such analysis of what type the closure returns is more ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out soon after posting, funny how that happens.

The question has the answer, because the closure is returning something, so we just need to know what type is being returned.

The closure in question is returning a `NavigationLink`

> NavigationLink<Label, Destination> where Label: View, Destination: View

from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/).

The Destination parameter of `NavigationLink` is explicitly identified as a `LandmarkDetail` object. The Label parameter is defined by the trailing closure. Here's the answer.

```
ForEach(filteredLandmarks) {
  (landmark: Landmark) -> NavigationLink<LandmarkRow, LandmarkDetail> in
      NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
    }
}
```